# Prove, for ever $x$ in a maximal subgroup there is a $n$ such that $p^n x \in G$.

Tags: group-theory

The third part of this question is giving me problems. I think I'm missing something trivial (?).

> Consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a group under addition.
>
> 1. Prove, using Zorn's Lemma, that there is a subgroup $G$ of $\mathbb{R}$ which is maximal w.r.t. the property that $1\not \in G$.
> 2. Suppose $G$ is as in (1.). Show that there is a unique prime number $p$ such that $p\in G$.
> 3. Let $p$ be as in (2.). Prove that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there is an $n\geqslant 0$ such that $p^n x\in G$.

#### Proof

I've been able to prove 1. and 2. but for 3. I seem to be missing a way of putting 1. and 2. together. I was thinking of the following:

Let $G$ be a maximal subgroup with $1\not \in G$. Choose an $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If $x\in G$ then $n=0$ is enough.

Now let $x\not \in G$. Consider $H:= \langle G \cup \{x\}\rangle$. Then $1\in H$ because $G$ was maximal. Which implies $1=g+k\cdot x$ for a certain $g\in G$ and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

This implies $p = p\cdot g + pkx$ which implies $pkx \in G$ (because $p\in G$).

However, how should I continue, how can I use (2.)? (the fact that $p$ is the only prime in $G$)? Any tips?

#### EDIT

Inspired by Derek Holt, I completed the proof as follows:

First notice that 2. implies $G\cap \mathbb{Z} = \langle p \rangle$.

Now once again let $x\not \in G$ and consider $\langle G \cup \{x\}\rangle$, then $1$ must be in this group, which implies $1 = g_0+k_0x$ for certain $g_0, k_0$. Or $p=p\cdot g_0+pk_0x$, which implies $pk_0x \in G$.

Now consider $px$, if $px\in G$ we are done, else consider $\langle G \cup \{px\}\rangle$ which must contain 1 due to maximality of $G$. So $1 = g_1+\tilde k_0px$ for certain $g_1, \tilde k_0$. Which implies $\tilde k_0 px -1 \in G\Rightarrow k_0 \tilde k_0px - k_0 \in G$ but since $k_0px\in G$ combining these results in $k_0 \in G$. Howver $k_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus $k_0 \in G\cap \mathbb{Z} = \langle p\rangle$. I.e. $k_0 = k_1\cdot p$ for a certain $k_1$ where $|k_1| < |k_0|$.

This implies $k_0px = k_1p^2x \in G$.

This process can be continued untill $|k_{n-1}| = 1$ which results in $p^nx \in G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative proof of 3, which I like better. Let $Q = {\mathbb R}/G$ be the quotient group. Then the image $\bar{1}$ of $1$ in $Q$ has order $p$. The maximality condition implies that $\langle \bar{1} \rangle$ is contained in all nontrivial subgroups of $Q$.

Part 3 says that all elements of $Q$ have order a power of $p$. Suppose not. Then there exists $x \in {\mathbb R}$ such that the order of its image $\bar{x}$ in $Q$ is either infinite or is a prime other than $p$. In either case $\langle \bar{x} \rangle$ has no subgroup of order $p$, so cannot contain $\langle \bar{1} \rangle$, contradiction.

Comment: This looks pretty cool, but could you elaborate why the maximality condition implies $\langle \overline 1\rangle$ is containerd in all nontrivial subgroups of $Q$?

Comment: If there was some nontrivial subgroup $\bar{H} < Q$ with $\langle \bar{1} \rangle \not\le \bar{H}$, then the inverse image $H$ of $\bar{H}$ in ${\mathbb R}$ would properly contain $G$ and not contain $1$, contradicting the maximality of $G$.

Answer (score 4):

If $x \in G$ we are done so suppose not. Then by maximality of $G$, we must have $1 \in G + \langle x \rangle$, so there exists $k_0 \in {\mathbb Z}$ with $k_0 x - 1 \in G$, and hence $k_0 p x \in G$.

Similarly, if $px \in G$ we are done so suppose not. Then $1 \in G + \langle px \rangle$, so there exists $k_1 \in {\mathbb Z}$ with $k_1 p x - 1 \in G$. Hence $(k_1 + rk_0)px - 1 \in G$ for all $r \in {\mathbb Z}$, and so we can choose $k_1$ with $|k_1| < |k_0|$. Then $k_1 p^2 x \in G$.

Carrying on like this, if $p^2x \not\in G$ then we find $k_2$ with $|k_2| < |k_1|$ and $k_2p^2x - 1 \in G$, etc, and since $|k_0| > |k_1| > |k_2| > \cdots$, the process must eventually stop with $p^nx \in G$ for some $n$.

Comment: Small typo, should be $k_1p+rk_0$. (+1 by the way)

Comment: Fixed - but I have thought of a different proof.

Comment: I don't get why $(k_1 + rk_0)px-1\in G$ and this for all $r\in \mathbb{Z}$ implies that you choose $k_1$ such that $|k_1|<|k_0|$. Doesn't *there exists $k_1\in \mathbb{Z}$ ...* fix the possible $k_1$'s?  However your method inspired me for a similar solution. (Using part 2. of the exercise), I altered the question with that solution. I'll check into your short and elegant (?) proof now :)